flink checkpoint interval setting
I have a flink task that uses RocksDB StateBackend, and the checkpoint configuration is a minimum interval of 3 minutes and a timeout of five minutes.
When I tested the checkpoint recovery mechanism, the task was running fine. When I killed a taskmanager to simulate a failure and restarted, the task was delayed from the previous checkpoint, and then back pressure was generated. Then the checkpoint time becomes longer, it may even fail, and the task continues to be delayed. But when I set the checkpoint configuration to a minimum interval of 1 minute, and the timeout is also 1 minute, and re-execute the above steps, the task seems to be able to complete the recovery well and run normally. I know that the longer the checkpoint interval means more data needs to be recovered, and the shorter the interval, the higher the checkpoint overhead will be. In my case my question is

Does it mean that my task capacity is not large enough to consume data delayed by more than three minutes? However, judging from historical monitoring, when the task is running normally, the resource consumption is not particularly large.
How to evaluate a reasonable checkpoint interval?

I modified the checkpoint interval and found that at a one-minute interval, my task could resume normally from the previous checkpoint, quickly catch up with the historical data, and then run normally.

When I tested, the logic of the sink function directly ignored the output, so there was no external sink logic. I did some tests and I feel that the bottleneck should be on RocksDB, but I don't know how to improve it. My phenomenon is probably like this

I changed the method of deploying the machine from the original cloud service provider's cloud disk to a local SSD, and mounted two disks. iops should be improved. Judging from the results, the consumption power of the program has improved than before.
However, the program still does not catch up very quickly, and the CPU utilization cannot increase. I looked at the monitoring, as shown below. Most of the disk operations are writes, and few read operations. The write disk request time seems to be a bit high, but the amount of data written is not large 。



In order to avoid writing more disks during testing, I configured the following parameters:
taskmanager.memory.managed.fraction: "0.5"
state.backend.rocksdb.memory.write-buffer-ratio: "0.7"
state.backend.rocksdb.localdir: /data/rocksdb-state,/data2/rocksdb-state


Will the checkpoint size become larger and larger under delay? It is several times larger than during normal operation. How to understand this?


Something can't quickly handle the additional load while the recovered job is catching up. From what you've said, my guess is that it's the external system(s) being written to by the sink(s), or perhaps the network between Flink and those external systems.

I update my question,add more monitor graph and information, please help~thank you

Do you have incremental checkpointing enabled? This makes a huge difference during recovery.
